# How to solve Keras conv2d input shape error?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am having problems with the input shape while trying to create a convolutional neural network.

My dataset has 164 images 250x250 pixels (123 imgs for training and the remaining for test)

The code:

```py
def conv_neural_net(x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test):

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(16, (3,3), padding="same", activation='relu', input_shape=(250,250,1)))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(1,1)))

    model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3), padding="same", activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(1,1)))

    model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3), padding="same", activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(1,1)))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(rate=0.2))
    model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10)

    _, accuracy = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
    print('Accuracy: %.2f' % (accuracy*100))

    return model
```

I have an error while trying to fit

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-235-d83533a1c9fa> in <module>
----> 1 conv_neural_net(x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test)

<ipython-input-234-d7ddc86e3578> in conv_neural_net(x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test)
     27 
     28     model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
---> 29     model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10)
     30 
     31     _, accuracy = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
    950             sample_weight=sample_weight,
    951             class_weight=class_weight,
--> 952             batch_size=batch_size)
    953         # Prepare validation data.
    954         do_validation = False

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, check_array_lengths, batch_size)
    749             feed_input_shapes,
    750             check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't enforce the batch size.
--> 751             exception_prefix='input')
    752 
    753         if y is not None:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    126                         ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have ' +
    127                         str(len(shape)) + ' dimensions, but got array '
--> 128                         'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
    129                 if not check_batch_axis:
    130                     data_shape = data_shape[1:]

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_154_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (123, 250, 250)
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Are these images grayscale?

Comment: Yes, they were converted with open cv

Answer (score 0):

The required shape involves "channels". (RGB has 3 channels, RGBA has 4 channels, black and white has 1 channel)

All you need is to add the channels dimension to your input data.

```
x_train = x_train.reshape((123,250,250,1))    
x_test = x_test.reshape((164-123,250,250,1))
```

Comment: Now I have

Error when checking target: expected dense_65 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (123, 250, 250, 1)

Comment: My y_train is a matrix with the same dimensions of x_train (123,250,250). But instead of the pixel value, it contains 0 or 1, which are the classes I want to predict. What should be the target shape if not this?

Comment: The same rule. You need channels. You're outputting from conv layers.

Comment: But if you want to output images, you cannot use  `Flatten` and stuff like that. You need to keep the image shape.

Comment: There is a lot of updates you need to do in your model to output the same shape of X, you should study a "U-net" design for that.

Comment: I am trying to output classes, not images. So I reshaped y_train to contain the channel dimension (123,250,250,1). Same dimensions as x_train. And still have error when checking the target: expected dense_77 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (123, 250, 250, 1)

Comment: But why does Y have the shape of an image then? Do you want to classify images (Y should be `(samples, classes)`) or do you want to classify pixels (Y should be images like `(samples, h, w, channels)`)?

Comment: Pixels! So for every pixel I have a target 0 or 1. That's why x_train and y_train have the same shape (samples=123, h=250, w=250, channels=1)

Comment: So you are outputting "images", and you will need a U-net like model for that. (You need the model to output things with the same shape as your Y). But since you used a lot of `MaxPooling` layers, you changed the size of the image. Then you used a `Flatten` (eliminated the pixels dimension). The U-net is something that will not use `Flatten`, but will use `UpSampling` to increase the image size again, will conatenate parts of the shrinking side with the increasing side, in order to output something with the original size.